# Создание папок с папками внутри

Tags: cmd, windows-10

Необходим скрипт который создает допустим папку 1 и помещает в нее 8 папок: название должны быть рандомные и один файл,потом в каждую так же копирует файл, и так надо сделать четыре уровней. Вот пример как должно получится (просто каталог = рандомное название)

```
Каталог1
 Каталог
 index.html
  Каталог
  index.html
   Каталог
   index.html
    Каталог
    index.html
 Каталог
 Каталог
 Каталог
 Каталог
 Каталог
 Каталог
 Каталог
 index.html
```

Сейчас используется:

```
`
@Echo Off 
Set PassLenght=16 
set var=0 
set var1=4 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions 
Set TotalChars=65 
Set CharSet=QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm0123456789 
:Loop 
Set /A Rnd=%TotalChars%*%Random%/32768 
Set Pswd=!CharSet:~%Rnd%,1!%Pswd% 
Set /A PassLenght-=1 
If %PassLenght% GTR 0 GoTo Loop 
mkdir %pswd% 
copy index.html %pswd% 
cd %pswd% 
set /a var=%var%+1 
IF %var%==%var1% goto end 
goto loop 
:end 
pause
`
```

и создает такую иерархию:

```
│ 
└───Yg4JZGTPqnNgJ 
----│---index.html 
----│ 
----└───CYg4JZGTPqnNgJ 
--------│---index.html 
--------│ 
--------└───5CYg4JZGTPqnNgJ 
------------│---index.html 
------------│ 
------------└───w5CYg4JZGTPqnNgJ 
--------------------index.html
```

Обязательное условие каждого каталога: нужно поместить в каждый каталог файл index.html (В каждом каталоге по четыре папок, в другой еще 4, третьей ...

Скрипт на cmd НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО, можно на PowerShell

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: например не могу понять как это можно организовать

Comment: Есть какой-то, какой угодно код?

Comment: Есть
https://hastebin.com/onavubuyum.sql
(Делает 4 папки с рандомным названием и в каждую копирует index.html, но надо еще в этих созданных создать по папке и так далее)

Comment: Уточнения: a)`cmd` - обязательное условие или, скажем, `powershell` - тоже ОК? b) какая версия Windows/DOS/FreeDOS?

Comment: cmd - необязательно, но это единственное что я знаю больше чем уровень "перейти в папку,удалить папку" Windows 10

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90058/discussion-between-sasha0552-and-alex-yu).